# Installing node.js on Windows CE

Tags: node.js

Can node.js be installed in Windows CE Operating System? I have a project requirement where I need to provide an abstraction between Baracudda Server and my HTML page for security purpose.
I am a newbie on node.js, so please forgive my ignorance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any experience regarding installing node.js on an ARM processor in an embedded device?

Comment: Since your question was raised, this google group has been discussing both CE and ARM and looks like the answer is still 'No' for both.